# Gatsby Typescript : External module function import throws ReferenceError

Tags: typescript, gatsby

I'm working on some Gatsby sites' components & helpers, bundled as a custom npm module ([statikon](https://github.com/Skaant/statikon)).

Core Gatsby site project and `statikon` helper module are both built on TypeScript.

My issue is that `gatsby-node.ts` file throw `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'f' before initialization` when I try to import a function from external module into the `createPages` function.

### What works

#### Importing components

Importing template through `createPage`'s `component` works well.

```js
/* gatsby-node.ts */

// ... Inside createPages
  createPage({
    component: path.resolve("./src/templates/default.template.tsx"),
```

I made a small proxy in the core Gatsby site to bind SCSS.

```js
/* ./src/templates/default.template.tsx */

import "../styles/global.scss";
import { DefaultTemplate } from "statikon";

export default DefaultTemplate;
```

**Note that templates seem to run in a second phase, after gatsby-node was executed.**

#### Importing types

It is also possible to import type in `gatsby-node.ts` without error.

```js
/* gatsby-node.ts */

import { DefaultTemplateContext } from "statikon";

// ... Inside createPages
  createPage({
    context: {} as DefaultTemplateContext,
```

**Note that types are ignored when gatsby node is transpiled to JS, aren't called at runtime and so on are "undefined-proof".**

### What fails

Issue appears when I try to import a function from the external module `statikon` into `gatsby-node.ts`.

Let's see this very simple helper function :

```js
/* statikon/src/helpers/richTextToString.ts */

import { TextRichTextItemResponse } from "@notionhq/client/build/src/api-endpoints";

function richTextToString(texts: TextRichTextItemResponse[]): string {
  return texts
    .map(({ plain_text }) => {
      return plain_text;
    })
    .join(" ");
}

export default richTextToString;
```

Importing it in `gatsby-node` without using it doesn't fail :

```
/* gatsby-node.ts */

import richTextToString from "statikon/src/helpers/richTextToString";
```

But, when called, the `ReferenceError` is thrown.

```
/* gatsby-node.ts */

// ... Inside createPages
  createPage({
    // ...
    path:
      url.type === "rich_text"
        ? richTextToString(url.rich_text as TextRichTextItemResponse[])
        : page.id,
```

**Message : `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'f' before initialization`.**

#### What I tried to fix issue

##### 1. Helper method without dependency

Online, I found that this error may be caused by circular dependency.

I tried to export the method without depending on any package, **but `gatsby-node.ts` still throws**.

```js
/* statikon/src/helpers/richTextToString.ts */

// import { TextRichTextItemResponse } from "@notionhq/client/build/src/api-endpoints";

function richTextToString(texts: { plain_text: string }[]): string {
```

##### 2. Transpiling module before import

I also tried running `tsc --build` the `statikon` module to output inside `statikon/build` folder.

As I can import such other module function inside `gatsby-node`, I though it could make the trick but I still had issue when launching Gatsby.

```js
/* gatsby-node.ts */

import richTextToString from "statikon/build/helpers/richTextToString";
```

### How to fix this issue ?

I'm really having a hard time solving this.

How other modules can expose functions that can be imported inside `gatsby-node.ts` while mine `statikon` module can't ?

I'm sure I'm missing some hint about bundling process but cannot see it.

Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a circular dependency issue. It is kind of weird as the file does not import anything in your source. It might be due to using `export default` which in general in rather bad practise. Any particular reason to use it?
Please check if `export function richTextToString` fixes the issue.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't change the deal. I guess it is a Gastby context issue and I'll have to post in their repository for an answer.
Plus, why would you consider default export a bad practice ? Is it for naming issue ?

Comment: @imrok did you ever figure this out? Facing the exact same issue right now

Comment: @harryisaac no, sadly. I'm currently working on decoupling querying (to run before gastby build and to CACHE it) instead of combining both tasks :)